# MouseRightClick on ListBox crashes the app

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

When I do the mouse right click on my empty listbox, the whole app just crashes and I don't even know how to debug this, where to put `try-catch` and so on.

Have anybody encountered such problem? Any ideas on how to solve that issue?

Here's my XAML on the listbox:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="LstStat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="129" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"
             ItemsSource="{Binding StatisticsQueries}" Cursor="Arrow">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="18" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Maybe the XAML is somehow wrong?

### UPDATE

Here're the Bindings from .cs

```
public ObservableCollection<Query> StatisticsQueries { get; private set; }
private void FillStatisticsList()
{
    const string statsQuery = "SELECT * FROM cached_queries WHERE is_statistics IS TRUE;";
    var connection = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseModel.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();

    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(statsQuery, connection);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    StatisticsQueries = new ObservableCollection<Query>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        StatisticsQueries.Add(new Query
        {
            Id = reader["id"].ToString(),
            Autoschool = reader["autoschool"].ToString(),
            IsStatistics = reader["is_statistics"].ToString(),
            Name = reader["query_name"].ToString(),
            Text = reader["query_text"].ToString()
        });
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

And here's what I do on `Window_Loaded` event:

```
await Task.Run(() => FillStatisticsList());
```

That's all code connected with my ListBox, but it has nothing to do with the RightMouseClick... Why it doesn't crash on any other click or something?

Comment: "I don't even know how to debug this" - that's the source for many questions on Stack Overflow. Maybe you want to learn how to debug. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: You need to show us the .cs

Comment: If nothing else helps, set up [WER Localdumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then open the dump in Visual Studio.

Comment: What does it mean "crashes"? What exception do you get?

Comment: @user35443 I literally get the crash. No exceptions. If I knew where to put `try-catch`, I would post the exception, but it just says 'The program stopped working...'

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading: where is a Mouseclick event handler/subscription? Please do some meaningful editing. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell I'm sorry if the title is that bad. The thing is that there're absolutely no mouseclick event handlers/subscriptions. The bunch of code  is what israelaltar asked to post, it is the related Binding code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody!
Solved it by disabling the right mouse click on my ListBox.

```
private void LstStat_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void LstStat_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do the following: include the try-catch block and show the error message:

```
private void FillStatisticsList()
{
    try
    {
        const string statsQuery = "SELECT * FROM cached_queries WHERE is_statistics IS TRUE;";
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseModel.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(statsQuery, connection);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        StatisticsQueries = new ObservableCollection<Query>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            StatisticsQueries.Add(new Query
            {
                Id = reader["id"].ToString(),
                Autoschool = reader["autoschool"].ToString(),
                IsStatistics = reader["is_statistics"].ToString(),
                Name = reader["query_name"].ToString(),
                Text = reader["query_text"].ToString()
            });
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

Hope this may help.